# 8- bit Assembly addition

Tags: assembly

I am learning Assembly and I got the assignment to make addition of 2 decimal numbers. I have to use Microprotsessor Simulator- Version 5.0 that is a 8-bit Assembly programm.

I managed to get the adding of one digit numbers but is it possible to make it so that I can add multiple digit numbers. I'll paste my current solution:

```
CLO
Start:
    MOV AL, 00
    MOV CL, 80
    MOV DL, C0
Clear:
    MOV [DL],AL
    INC DL
    CMP DL, C6
    JNZ Clear
    MOV DL, C0
Rep:
        IN 00
        MOV [DL], AL
        SUB AL, 30
        MOV [CL], AL
        INC DL
        INC CL
        CMP AL, 82
        JZ  Sum    
        MOV AL, 2B ; + märk
        MOV [DL], AL
        INC DL
        JMP Rep
Sum:
    MOV AL, 3D
    MOV [DL], AL
    INC DL
    MOV AL, [81]
    MOV BL, [80]
    ADD AL, BL
    MOV [CL], AL

    CMP AL, 0A
    JNS Decii
    ADD AL, 30
    MOV [DL], AL
    IN 00
    CMP AL, 20
    JZ Start
Decii:
    DIV AL, 0A
    ADD AL, 30
    MOV [DL], AL
    INC DL
    MOV AL, [82]
    SUB AL, 0A
    ADD AL, 30
    MOV [DL], AL
    IN 00
    CMP AL, 20
    JZ Start
END
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Two digit numbers fit in 8 bits, so you just need to be able to input two digit numbers into a byte and output a byte as two digit number.  The formula for a two digit number from two individual digits is  number = first × 10 + second, and the reverse for output is first = number / 10, and second = number % 10.